# Error in adding a new key in a dict of graph node object in Python

Tags: python, neo4j

I was playing with neo4j database and I got stuck when I want to add a list to node property.
Basically What i want to add a new entry "links_in" to a node property that is the list of incoming node properties to that node

The following are the nodes:

```
   | n                                                                       
---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | (n4096:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/"})             
 2 | (n4097:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services"})             
 3 | (n4098:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services#solution"})    
 4 | (n4099:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services#consult"})     
 5 | (n4100:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services#technologies"})
 6 | (n4101:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/about"})                    
 7 | (n4102:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/careers"})                  
 8 | (n4103:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/blog"})                     
 9 | (n4104:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/contact"})
```

and the node relationships are as follows:

```
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/our-services"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/our-services#solution"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/our-services#consult"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/our-services#technologies"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/about"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/careers"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/blog"
"http://www.example.org/" -> "http://www.example.org/cont"
```

And I was expecting the output as:

```
   | n                                                                       
---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | (n4096:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/","links_in":[]})             
 2 | (n4097:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services","links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]})             
 3 | (n4098:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services#solution,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})    
 4 | (n4099:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services#consult,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})     
 5 | (n4100:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/our-services#technologies,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})
 6 | (n4101:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/about,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})                    
 7 | (n4102:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/careers,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})                  
 8 | (n4103:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/blog,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})                     
 9 | (n4104:Site {name:"http://www.example.org/contact,"links_in":["http://www.example.org/"]"})
```

So I tried the following method to get the above result:

```
def FindLinks():
    links_in = []
    for i in graph.cypher.execute("match n return n"):
        for j in graph.cypher.execute("match ()-[r:ok]->(n) where n.name ='%s' return r"%i.n.properties['name']):
            if graph.node(i.n.ref).properties.has_key('links_in'): 
                graph.node(i.n.ref).properties["links_in"].append(j.r.start_node.properties)
            else:
                links_in.append(j.r.start_node.properties)
        graph.node(i.n.ref).properties.update({"links_in":links_in})
        links_in = []
```

But I got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-e762c2030688> in <module>()
      5         else:
      6             links_in.append(j.r.start_node.properties)
----> 7     graph.node(i.n.ref).properties.update({"links_in":links_in})
      8     links_in = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/core.pyc in update(self, iterable, **kwargs)
   1071                     self[key] = iterable[key]
   1072             except (AttributeError, TypeError):
-> 1073                 for key, value in iterable:
   1074                     self[key] = value
   1075         for key in kwargs:

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So What should I do ?

Comment: Please post the rest of the traceback. It contains useful information, such as which line the error occurred on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to recreate this problem and have just made a commit to fix the incorrect/unhelpful error message. This will be released in py2neo 2.0.1.

The underlying problem is actually the assignment of an illegal property type. You are attempting to set a property value consisting of a list of PropertySet objects. Lists in Neo4j may only contain primitive types and they must be homogenous. For more information, look here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html.